# Two lines of Python code result in 3 execution blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am experimenting with Python opcodes, and I am surprised to see the output of `dis.dis` below. Given are the following two lines:

```
[i for i in range(10)]
print("OK")
```

As you can see, these two lines result in 3 blocks. Why does the 1st and 3rd block belong to the first line? Is this also executed in this order? I would expect such out-of-order instructions from a `C` or `C++` compiler but I don't understand the 3rd block:

```
1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x109664540, file "example.py", line 1>)
            2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
            4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
            6 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
            8 LOAD_CONST               2 (10)
            10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
            12 GET_ITER
            14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
            16 POP_TOP

2          18 LOAD_NAME                1 (print)
            20 LOAD_CONST               3 ('OK')
            22 CALL_FUNCTION            1
            24 POP_TOP
            26 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
            28 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x109664540, file "test", line 1>:
1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
            2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 14)
            6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
            8 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
            10 LIST_APPEND              2
            12 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

P.S. For what are `>>`?
The documentation describes them as `a labelled instruction, indicated with >>,` but I can't apply this comment on the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<listcomp>` is a separate object created by the interpreter when desugaring the list comprehension. It serves to isolate the comprehension namespace (the loop variable `i`) and build the list. It is created first, then called after some preparation and finally discarded.

---

You can see the helper being created right at the start:

```
1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x109664540, file "example.py", line 1>)
            2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
            4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
```

Since CPython is a stack-based VM, previous instructions can put arguments for later instructions on the stack.
Here you can see the code object (the third block in your disassembly) being loaded, a name being loaded and finally a function being created from what has just been added to the stack. Note that you can actually see this function, e.g. if there is an error in the comprehension it shows up on the traceback.

Next, Python creates an iterator over the range:

```
        6 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
        8 LOAD_CONST               2 (10)
        10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
        12 GET_ITER
```

This loads the range function, its argument and then applies that —- we now have `range(10)` at the top of the stack. Finally, the range is removed and replace it with its iterator.

Finally, Python calls the helper function:

```
        14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
```

Remember that our stack was previously filled with the helper function `<listcomp>` and the range iterator. Everything else is gone from the stack. So here Python calls the helper function with the range iterator as its argument. The helper returns the list resulting from the list comprehension.

---

- For what are `>>`?

They are visualizations of possible jumps/branches in the bytecode execution.

For example, a `for` loop can either be done (jump to the end of the loop) or have another item (jump to the start of the loop). You can see this in your disassembly:

```
  >>    4 FOR_ITER                 8 (to 14)
        6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
        8 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
        10 LIST_APPEND              2
        12 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
   >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Instruction 4 is the iteration of a loop (namely in the list comprehension). Its argument (to the right) is the block size, namely 8. This means when done, it jumps `to 14` — the return instruction marked with `>>`. Since the loop must repeat for every item, its last instruction 12 is a jump to the loop instruction at 4 — also marked with `>>`.